# Lucene Based Searching

Tags: lucene

I've a problem in Lucene based searching. I have designed a document with five fields. Consider the document be Address with addressline1, addressline2, city, state and pin. If a search is to be  performed, then the search has be done in all the fields, so I'm using boolean term queries. So the results would be retrieved. Now I also have to respond not only with responses but also with the matching field. For eg if the city field matches the search, then I should respond as city matches the search along with the actual search response. Is there are any lucene api to accommodate this?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11697341/465710

Comment: NO I'm not asking about joins. 
The document is as below,
DOcument
{
Field firstName, Field middleName;}
So for searching all field I use boolean term queries like this,
Query q= new BooleanQuery().add(new TermQuery("FirstName","name"),true);
q.add(new TermQuery("MiddleName,"name");. So the results would be apparent. BUt the reponse should be of
<reponse>
<firstname>name</firstName>
<middleName>SomeOtherName</middleName>
<matching>firstName</matching>   ------> how to determine this?
</response>

Comment: You want to know which field matched the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no simple solution to find out which field matched the query.

Your options are:

1. try using hit highlighter (it knows where the match occurred but it's noticeably slow on large result sets)
2. fiddle with IndexSearcher's explain method
3. build your custom solution

[Hit highlighter experience and workaround findings.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201207.mbox/%3CCABEREKHNn1wKFo2rYNq+Zi4JK0D57FG-RrMF29qupzOdy_6ykw@mail.gmail.com%3E)

IMHO it shouldn't be hard to implement that yourself, since Lucene in some point in time surely knows which field yielded a match, but it discards that information as unnecessary weight by the time it composes your response.
I stumbled upon [this custom approach](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201005.mbox/%3C901394.60057.qm@web81101.mail.mud.yahoo.com%3E).

[Try to find more resources on search-lucene.com, the best Lucene/Solr related search engine.](http://search-lucene.com/?page=0&q=which%20field%20has%20a%20match&fc_project=Lucene)

Comment: Mbonaci,

This solution will best fit my problem,

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201207.mbox/%3CCABEREKHNn1wKFo2rYNq+Zi4JK0D57FG-RrMF29qupzOdy_6ykw@mail.gmail.com%3E

The concerns within me is that, to do a binary analysis for boolean query  and to combine these results with the parent result.

Comment: I'm glad the info helped. Maybe you should try to contact Ashish Jaen to see what he ended up using as a solution to this problem. Shouldn't be too hard to figure out his mail address.