# Determine which fields were matched in lucene multifield query

Tags: lucene

I have a multi-field search in Lucene over about 10 fields. When displaying the results I would like to  find out which field(s) were actually matched on.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trivial, but there are couple of ways to find out "which field matched" the query.

Take a look at [this recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702038/lucene-based-searching/11705721#11705721).